Why is there a difference between curve swap rate and market swap rate?
I am constructing an ESTR curve from inter-meeting OIS swaps (tickers EESFXA Curncy in BBG) as per below
import QuantLib as ql

ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = ql.Date(13, 12, 2024)

swap_data = [(ql.Date(13,12,2024), ql.Date(18,12,2024), 0.03167), (ql.Date(18,12,2024), ql.Date(5,2,2025), 0.02917), (ql.Date(5,2,2025), ql.Date(12,3,2025), 0.02627), (ql.Date(12,3,2025), ql.Date(23,4,2025), 0.02303)]
helpers = []
for row in swap_data:
    helpers.append(
        ql.DatedOISRateHelper(
            row[0],
            row[1],
            ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(row[2])),
            ql.Estr()
        )
    )
day_count = ql.Actual360()
curve = ql.PiecewiseFlatForward(ql.Date(13, 12, 2024), helpers, day_count)
curve.enableExtrapolation()

When I then try to query the curve as follows
today = ql.Date(13, 12, 2024)
tgt = ql.TARGET()
spot = tgt.advance(today, ql.Period(2, ql.Days))
end_date = tgt.advance(spot, ql.Period('2m'))

curve.forwardRate(spot, end_date, ql.Actual360(), ql.Compounded, ql.Daily).rate()

I get the number to be ~2.8598
The market however prices the 2 month ESTR swap (ticker EESWEB Curncy in BBG) for those dates at ~2.8667
Why does this discrepancy appear?

Bid offer for 1. Timing differences. Stale prices. + 1000 other things.

@user68819 ok so are u saying I have done all correctly on my end and it's within the  margin of error to get such a difference? I used mids for input data for meeting date swaps as well as for 2m swap comparison

No I am just saying for that level of error it seems like it could be one of the issues above. It doesn't seem like it's something fundamentally wrong.

@user68819 understood thank you :)

The floating-rate leg of an OIS pays daily-compounded ESTR.  The fixed-rate leg, which is the one quoted by the market, pays a simple rate.  Asking for that rate gives you what you expect:
print(curve.forwardRate(spot, end_date, ql.Actual360(), ql.Simple).rate())
0.028667328384901276

However, I would be careful about asking the curve for the rate.  For one thing, it wouldn't work when the fixed leg has more than one coupon; in that case, the quoted rate is not easily calculated, because it's the rate that all fixed coupons should pay for the swap to be fair, and it doesn't correspond to any one forward rate on the curve.  Instead, I would instantiate the corresponding OIS and ask it for its fair rate (there's a fairRate method for that).

Thank you! Much appreciated

Its pretty easy to build a log-linearly interpolated curve in something like Excel or even on paper for these very short dated, separable and contiguous instruments. If you are uncertain if you have configured it correctly in Quantlib do a benchmark.
Here is benchmark from rateslib:
from rateslib import *  # Python 3.12, rateslib 1.6.0

curve = Curve(
    nodes={
        dt(2024, 12, 13): 1.0,
        dt(2024, 12, 18): 1.0,
        dt(2025, 2, 5): 1.0,
        dt(2025, 3, 16): 1.0,
    },
    convention="act360",
    calendar="tgt",
    id="estr"
)

solver = Solver(
    curves=[curve],
    instruments=[
        IRS(dt(2024, 12, 13), dt(2024, 12, 18), spec="eur_irs", curves="estr"),
        IRS(dt(2024, 12, 18), dt(2025, 2, 5), spec="eur_irs", curves="estr"),
        IRS(dt(2025, 2, 5), dt(2025, 3, 12), spec="eur_irs", curves="estr")
    ],
    s=[3.167, 2.917, 2.627]
)

With the results:
curve.rate(dt(2024, 12, 17), "2m")  # 2.866733
IRS(dt(2024, 12, 17), "2m", spec="eur_irs", curves="estr").rate(solver=solver)  # 2.866733

No idea how you are getting 2.8598.
